# redirect in n seconds and pass values

Tags: php, javascript

I have page A and B. Once page A loads I will get input from the user. After 60 seconds, the page will automatically redirect to Page B. I did with the below code, but values are not getting passed.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function printVal()
     {
       printVal.counter--;
       document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = printVal.counter;
       if(printVal.counter==0){
         window.location="next.php";
       }
     }

     function callfun()
     {
       setInterval(printVal,1000);
     }

     printVal.counter=61;
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="submit" value="Click Me" onclick="callfun()">
  <p id="timer"></p>
  <form method='post' action='next.php'>
     <input type='text' name='val'>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've to create a list. Once the user types something in the text box and presses enter it should go and add it in a list box. After 60 seconds, I want the values in the list box to be passed to next.php.

Comment: @jbabey all I said is that according to meta it's inappropriate to comment on it.

Comment: Ok, given the vast amounts of comments that explain to the asker why he might not receive enough attention I see every 'minute' on this site, I did not know it was inappropriate. I also did not badger him and it is the fist time I felt it was reasonable to point this out after visiting the askers profile page. For what it's worth, I'm sorry, I'll just IGNORE in the future.

Comment: Just to be shure there is no hate over here, I took the time to write (AND TEST) a detailed answer and working example code for the asker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `window.location` won't submit the values in your form to the new location. You'll have to submit the form instead.

```
if(printVal.counter==0)
    document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
}
```

Comment: well, I believe the asker actually could use `window.location`, if he sent his data as GET instead of post. Just as a note for future readers.

Comment: @GitaarLAB You're right but in this case it would be more work^^

Answer (score 1):

That's quite an extensive question to try and answer usefully.

Let's start with your listbox: you ask: `once user types something in text box and press enter it should go and add in a list box. and after 60 seconds i want the values in the list box to be passed to next.php`

Why would you put the data in a listbox, if the user will not do anything with (the data in) that listbox? So I guess your line of thinking was to use a listbox to hold seperate values you could then POST to your next.php.

Delimiting the value's you say? Ok, deal. Let's disregard json, ajax and so forth and 'teach you to how to fish' with some *simple* plain vanilla javascript. I'll leave modularizing up to you!

As a html input-element's name-attribute we can also specify an *array* like so: `<input "name=itm[]">` (you would also do this when making your 'listbox', aka `<select name="var[]" multiple="yes">`). Let's display them nicely in a list. So whenever you hit the enter-key in your textarea/inputfield an list-item containing an inputfield is added to the form.

When the timer hits zero you then need to submit the form using `form.submit()` (as Andreas also pointed out).

Here is a *simplified* yet fully working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>demo</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
   itmLi=document.createElement('li');
   itmInp=itmLi.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
   itmInp.type='text';
   itmInp.name='val[]';

   theItms=document.getElementById('theItems');

   fetchItem=function(el,evt){
      var itmAct, keyCode=(evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
      if (keyCode == 13){
         itmAct=theItms.appendChild(itmLi.cloneNode(true));
         itmAct.firstChild.value=el.value;
         el.value='';
         return false;
      }
   };


   theTmr=document.getElementById('tmrOut');
   myTimer=function(){
      var t=Number(theTmr.innerHTML);
      if(t){
         theTmr.innerHTML=t-1;
         window.setTimeout(myTimer,1000);
      } else {
         theItms.parentNode.submit();
      }
   };
   window.setTimeout(myTimer,1000);

   document.getElementById('inpTxt').focus(); //sigh.. firefox does not work AGAIN.
};
</script>

</head><body>

<p>Time left: <span id="tmrOut">60</span></p>

<textarea id="inpTxt" onkeyup="return fetchItem(this,event);"></textarea>

<form id="theForm" method="post" action="next.php">
<ul id="theItems"></ul>
</form>

</body></html>
```

And of course you can find a [working demo in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yYF8c/) (note that this demo runs for 10 seconds instead of 60).

Now your php-script `next.php` will receive *one* variable: `val` (as you already named it), but this variable is actually an array containing all items that were entered (separated by the enter-key).
Tada!

Since you only asked how to pass variables to php my answer stops here. If you need help on the receiving php-side I suggest you [RTM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php) first.

Good luck!!